# How to verify in AWS Cognito amplify if idToken and accessToken and refreshToken are valid?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Currently I trying to verify if a `refreshToken` is still valid after revoke it using the boto3 method. Any suggestion about how to do this?

I revoking the refresh token as follows:

```
def revoke_refresh_token(refresh_token):
    import boto3

    print(f"REVOKING TOKEN -> {refresh_token}")

    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
    client.revoke_token(
        Token=refresh_token,
        ClientId='MY_CLIENT_ID',
    )

    print("TOKEN REVOKED")

    return "TOKEN REVOKED"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate refresh tokens as you would with any other JWT token, by validating the JWT's structure, the signature and the claims. See this document for help on how to do that Cognito tokens: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html.

When it comes to checking if tokens have been revoked, I believe that you'll just need to build your app to handle tokens being revoked and redirect the user to sign-in when this happens. I am not aware of anyway you can currently validate refresh tokens, other than to perhaps attempt to generate new access/id tokens and see if you are rejected.